# How to solve $y'(x) = y(x) + y(x)^2 + x y(x)^3$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So firstly I realized this equation is not universal or linear.

Then I tried to use Laplace transform, but I'm getting some cubic equation on image-function which I'll have to reverse transform after I get the roots.

I was trying to find solution as something like $$y_0 = \frac{e^{g(x)}}{f(x)}$$
but couldnt find anything in simple functions.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: What are you getting for the Laplace transform? It should not be possible to take the Laplace transform of a nonlinear ODE

Comment: @kleineg, something like $s^3 t(s) = \frac{t(s)}{s^2} (s t(s) + s + t^2(s))$ and so I have to firstly solve it for $t(s)$, dont I?

Comment: $\mathscr L \left( y(x)^3 \right) \neq t(s)^3$

Comment: Sorry that took so long to get right, I wish there was a preview for comments. But the point remains, the Laplace transform of a nonlinear function of a variable is not the nonlinear function applied to the Laplace transform of that variable. It would require the convolution to be taken into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=e^xu$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=e^x\dfrac{du}{dx}+e^xu$

$\therefore e^x\dfrac{du}{dx}+e^xu=e^xu+e^{2x}u^2+xe^{3x}u^3$

$e^x\dfrac{du}{dx}=e^{2x}u^2+xe^{3x}u^3$

$\dfrac{du}{dx}=e^xu^2+xe^{2x}u^3$

Let $u=-\dfrac{1}{v}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{v^2}\dfrac{dv}{dx}$

$\therefore\dfrac{1}{v^2}\dfrac{dv}{dx}=\dfrac{e^x}{v^2}-\dfrac{xe^{2x}}{v^3}$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dx}=e^xv-xe^{2x}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $t=e^x$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{dx}=\dfrac{dv}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{dx}=e^x\dfrac{dv}{dt}$

$\therefore e^xv\dfrac{dv}{dt}=e^xv-xe^{2x}$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dt}=v-xe^x$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dt}-v=-t\ln t$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form.

Please follow the method in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf